# publish project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish

i try to publish and i get an error

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed. (The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v2.0'. This application requires 'v4.0'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH.)       0   0   HacmeBank_V2_Website

someone know how to resolve ?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your IIS settings are not matching.

If you go to your **IIS Manager** and navigate to **Application Pools** and look for the published(your Project name) folder

Select your **Published project** from the list

Click on **Basic Settings** from **Actions** pane

Change the .NET Framework Version to v4.0xxxxx

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem when installing Orchard CMS. Keep targeting v2.0. 
But find the simple solution: in IIS, on the Application Pools (the list with all application pools), you can find the 2nd setting top right list: "Set Application Pool Defaults.." change there the default from 2.0 to 4.0 et, voila.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your project is targeting the .net 4.0 framework, but there is a setting in your 'publish' flow that specifies .net 2.0

I've never published this way, but this error looks like something I've seen before integrating different libraries targeting different frameworks...

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

All above didn't solve my problem , just changed Targeted Framework in visual studio from 4.5 to 4.5.1 and Problem Solved